# how to read a cookie from browser in nextjs api

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I am setting my cookie in the layout.js component and can see it in the browser.

I have my api and I want to be able to read the cookie when a post is made and then do something with the value.

I have tried a few different packages to do this and I am getting 'undefined' for the cookie value

How can I read the value of the cookie in my `api.js` file?

**Layout.js**

```
 useEffect(() => {
    document.cookie = 'tagrid=322323932; path=/'
  })
```

pages/api.js

```
// import cookies from 'next-cookies'
import cookieCutter from 'cookie-cutter'
import Cookies from 'cookies'


// const cook = Object.keys(cookies).map((name) => cookies[name].toString())

export default async (req, res) => {
  const { method, body } = req
  if (method === 'POST') {
    res.statusCode = 200
    res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json')
    res.end(
      JSON.stringify({
        msg: body,
      }),
    )
    try {
      const cook = cookies.get('tagrid')
      // read cookie value
      console.log('cook', cook)
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error)
    }
  } else {
    res.status(200)
  }
}
```

**express.js**

```
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");

var cookieParser = require("cookie-parser");
var express = require('express');
const app = express();
app.use(cookieParser());

app.get('/', function(req, res){

  console.log('Cookies: ', req.cookies)

});
//Here we are configuring express to use body-parser as middle-ware.
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.listen(4000,() => {
  console.log("Started on PORT 4000");
})
```

Comment: I don't have the answer but maybe a helpful hint: Not all cookies can be read by JavaScript. For example, I set a cookie in express-session and explicitly configure the cookie to not be accessible via JS. It's a layer of security for users so that cookies can't be 'stolen' by malicious scripts, I think. (In my dev tools this is indicated by the flag 'http only')

Comment: Have you tried printing out document.cookie

Comment: document is not defined when i try

Answer (score 1):

https://www.npmjs.com/package/cookie-parser

cookie-parser is meant to be used as an express middleware, but most middlewares can be used directly as a function as well.

normally you'd use it in express like this:

```js
app.use(cookieParser());
```

But if you think about it, app.use takes a function and it passes that function the parameters `req, res, next`.  You can also pass it `req, res`, and a callback function (the callback function receives no parameters).

To use cookie-parser in your server-side script:

```js
import { cookieParser } from 'cookie-parser'

export default async (req, res) => {
  const callback = () => {
      const cook = req.cookies['tagrid'];
      console.log(cook);
  };
  cookieParser()(req, res, callback); 
};
```

Comment: http only is not ticked so I presume it should be able to be accessed

Comment: so I guess I need to send a GET request to my server to get the cookie?

Comment: Is your api.js file client-side? It looks to me like it's server-side because of the req and res parameters and the use of 'import' (which is a Node functionality).  I think in api.js you can use a cookie-parser middleware to allow you to access the cookie via req.cookies

Comment: I think you can use the middleware directly (without express) by doing `cookieParser()(req, res, function (req, res) { //your function using the cookie via req.cookies})`

Comment: my api is server side, but Im not sure if it's possible to implement the cookie-parser middleware or at least im not sure how as it's a nextjs server.

Comment: even in express I am trying `app.get('/', function(req, res){
    // check the request for existing cookies named "example"
  console.log('Cookies: ', req.cookies)
});` but not getting the cookie returned

Comment: in express did you use the middleware before this route? `const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser'); app.use(cookieParser()); app.get('/', ...`

Comment: I've added my express.js server

Comment: `import { cookieParser } from 'cookie-parser'

export default async (req, res) => {
  cookieParser()(req, res, (req, res) => { 
    const { method, body } = req
    if (method === 'POST') {
    res.statusCode = 200
    console.log('Cookies: ', req.cookies)
    }
  })
}` I've just tried this and I get an error, TypeError: Object(...) is not a function

Comment: Try it synchronously instead of with the callback? `export default async (req, res) => { cookieParser()(req,res); const {method, body } = req; ...`

Comment: I've updated the answer. The problem was that I thought `next()` was passed parameters and I was incorrect.  I have tested the above answer and it should solve your problem.

Comment: thank you for spending time on this but I still get the same errror,  It looks like in nextjs you can get access to the cookies with `req.cookies.tagrid`